# Proper *smart* shutdown of PostgreSQL server for PGDG apt packages under Ubuntu/Debian?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, debian, shutdown

I've installed PostgreSQL under Ubuntu 20.4 using the [PGDG apt repository](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt).

Each time I stop the DB server, e.g., with `sudo service postgresql stop`, the log says 'received **fast** shutdown request', but I'd like to initiate a [**smart** shutdown](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/server-shutdown.html).

I can achieve this by sending a TERM signal directly to the postmaster process. However, that seems to circumvent the whole systemd infrastructure. Ideally, I guess, there should be some version of `sudo systemctl stop postgresql ...`. But whatever I try, it always results in a fast shutdown.

Even the less high-level commands don't perform a smart shutdown - contrary to their documentation. Among other variations, I tried

```sh
sudo pg_ctlcluster --mode smart 13 main stop
sudo pg_ctlcluster 13 main stop -- --mode smart
```

and also editing `/etc/postgresql/13/main/pg_ctl.conf`. All to no avail.

So, what's the proper systemd-conform way to perform a smart shutdown?

Comment: Write a drop-in service file that changes the way systemd shuts down PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Debian / Ubuntu systems you need to add the option `--skip-systemctl-redirect` to the `pg_ctlcluster` command. Otherwise, the call to `postgres` will go through `systemd`, which can not handle shutdown mode.

From your example, it should be like:

```shell
sudo pg_ctlcluster --mode smart 13 main stop --skip-systemctl-redirect
```